# Does $L^p$ contractivity imply $L^p$ dissipativity?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

Does $L^p$ contractivity of an operator semigroup imply the $L^p$ dissipativity of the operator ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! A $C_0$-semigroup is contractive if and only if its generator is dissipative. This holds on every Banach space (thus in particular on $L^p$).

Comment: Thank you ! but how about L^p dissipativity ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Could you be a bit more specific? (i) On which Banach space is your semigroup defined? (ii) If this Banach space is not $L^p$, then what do you mean by $L^p$-dissipativity?

Comment: I am refering to the Following definiton: An operator is $L^p$-dissipative if $ (Au, |u|^{p-2}u) \leq 0$ for all $u\in C^{1}_0(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This still leaves the question open on which space your semigroup is defined. Morover, your definition of $L^p$-dissipativity only makes sense if you assume that the domain of the generator $A$ contains $C^1_0(\Omega)$. Could you clarify those points and include them in your question?

Comment: You are welcome sir ! the semigroup is defined on  L^p. I hope this will clarify.

Comment: Dear siki, you can and you **should** edit your own question rather than leaving all this extra information in the comments. (Perhaps you need to register an account first.)

Comment: You are right ! ok. Thank you.

Comment: To expand on the comment of @JochenGlueck: is the story in Section II.3.b, especially with Theorem 3.15, Proposition 3.23 and Example 3.26 (ii) the answer to your questions? https://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/de/forschung/agfa/members/engel-nagel_one-parameter-semigroups.pdf